# Time.now.utc returns next day

Tags: ruby

Why does `Time.now` return `2013-12-10 20:49:59 -0600` when `Time.now.utc` returns `2013-12-11 02:49:59 UTC`?

Comment: OK sorry, that is 2 A.M. not 2 P.M., now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Time.now is your local time.

Time.now.utc is the UTC time. Not your time.

read about UTC here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 0):

`Time.now` is evaluated in your time zone, which is `-0600` or 6 hours behind `utc`. You'll notice that if you add those 6 hours to the time you get from `Time.now`, you will get the `Time.now.utc` result.

Comment: Its not moving one day forward and subtracting six hours, its simply adding six hours to `Time.now`. `-6` means six hours behind `utc`. So `20:49:59` + `6:00:00` rolls over to the next day with a remainder of `02:49:59`